# Motd Python Script not working with imported libraries

Tags: ssh, python, motd

I am trying to edit the motd, but instead of bash scripts I want to use Python Scripts. It turns out, that Python Scripts do not work with imported libraries.

for example, this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Hello")
```

However, this does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import psutil
print(f"Users: {len(psutil.users())}")
```

When using the command `sudo update-motd` both scripts work, but when I try to connect via ssh only the upper script works.
I have already checked the following settings of ssh:

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config PrintMotd is enabled:

```
PrintMotd yes
```

in /etc/pam.d/ssh I have these settings for motd:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64

Comment: Does it work if you use a specific python instead of `env`? Something like `#!/usr/bin/python3`? I'm thinking that the default PATH when you connect via ssh is sending you to a different python version because you're using env and that python version doesn't have the necessary packages for some reason.

Comment: @terdon I changed the shebang to #!/usr/bin/python3, but unfortunately that leads to the same result

Comment: How did you install python 3 psutil? is the `PYTHONPATH` different for root compared to your non-privileged user(s)?

Comment: @steeldriver I installed psutil with `pip3 install psutil`. The command `python3 -c "import psutil as _; print(_.__path__)"` returns the installation path of psutil which is in my home directory: `/home/vulturemox/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil` (running it as sudo returns the same path). Is there a better way to install psutil?
When I run `echo $PYTHONPATH` it returns nothing (regardless of sudo). Should I define PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Right - so there's your problem - motd scripts are run as root. If you'd installed the `python3-psutil` package then it should work with the default `python3` from the repo (assuming you haven't done anything rash like remove the default `python3` of course).

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, now the script works after I installed python3-psutil, but what about other libraries such as colored?

Comment: AFAIK the same will apply to any packages that you have installed via `pip3` to your local user account

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:
The best way to solve this problem is to create a virtualenv (first install it with `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`)

Then initiate it with `virtualenv path/to/env`

Activate it `source path/to/env/bin/activate`

Install all dependencies with pip3

Then in the motd files I just changed the shebang to point at the virtualenv

```
#!path/to/env/bin/python3
```